# How to grab the view object from inside a Zend_Controller_Plugin Class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

I need to make a Zend Controller Plugin that repopulates a form with a request that is in every page on predispatch.   just need to figure how to grab the view object from inside the plugin and if there are any specifics for plugins as far as file directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out another solution of overriding the preDispatch of the action controller to set the form with the values of the request object.